# Displaying received data from serial port

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a problem working with the serial data received event handler. Half of the time the data displays on the textbox and half of the time does not. It should be the issue with cross thread operation.

This is my Arduino code:

```
int Loop = 1;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(Loop);
  Loop++;

  delay(1000);
}
```

And here is my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace arduino_test
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SerialPort sPort;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        initialiseArduino();
    }

    public void initialiseArduino()
    {
        sPort = new SerialPort();
        sPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        sPort.PortName = "COM16";
        sPort.Open();

        //sPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sPort_DataReceived);
    }

    void sPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string data = sp.ReadExisting();
        displayMessage(data);
    }

    public void displayMessage(string data)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<string>(displayMessage), new object[] { data });
            return;
        }
        textBox1.Text = data;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string data = sPort.ReadLine();
            textBox1.Text = data;
        }
    }
}
}
```

When i use the serial data received event handler, it gives me that problem even after invoking.

So i tried running a same thread operation by clicking a button and it works perfectly fine.

Can anybody advise me on what have i done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious difference and the cause of your problem is the two different way you do this.  You use `ReadExisting()` in your DataReceived event handler but `ReadLine()` in your Click event handler.

ReadExisting() just doesn't do what you hope it does, you only get 1 or 2 characters.  Whatever is "existing", never much since the DataReceived event fires quickly and modern desktop computers are very fast.  Then the event fires again and you read another 1 or 2 chars.  Your TextBox only shows whatever came last.

Use ReadLine() instead.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to update **displayMessage** method with

```
public void displayMessage(string data)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action<string>(displayMessage), new object[] { data });
        return;
    }
    **textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + data;**
}
```

In this way you'll never clear the textBox1 content and you'll have all values.

Please take in consideration (depends by your data) that your incoming data could contain control chars or other things that could not be nicely shown in textbox control.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the tip :-)